# Issues creating schema extensions using Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have logged into my dev tenant as the tenant admin and I'm trying to create a schema extension, but I get a `403 Authorization_RequestDenied`.

I have granted `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` to Graph Explorer and consented as admin, and double checked.

I'm running a POST against `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions` with the following payload:

```js
{
    "id":"GroupMetadata",
    "description": "some desc",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "groupType",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm getting the response:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3e3019c6-8ec5-4695-8ea3-b0aaf1ea1d25",
            "date": "2017-09-06T13:14:36"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, have you granted Admin Consent for this tenant?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT as stated I have double checked admin consent and that the correct right was added, and I log into Graph Explorer as my tenant admin. I might create my own adal app tomorrow and check using that instead.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what is happening just yet but I'm able to replicate this both in a local build and the public Graph Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, at least it's not me then :)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Creating a new native ADAL appreg, I was able to create my schema extension. Which means I need a separate app reg just to create the schema as ADAL native app's don't allow app permissions. And I need app permissions as I need both graph and CSOM - and hence cannot use MSAL native, which do offer app permissions ;) So, I'm hoping you can make the Graph Explorer work, which saves me from creating an extra app reg just to create the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **just** deployed a fix for this.  You can now Create/Update/Delete your schema definitions within Graph Explorer.

**NOTE**:  In order to make this work you **must** specify the `owner` property to be the appId of an app that you (the signed-in user) owns, in all POST, PATCH or DELETE operations.

The documentation will be updated shortly to reflect this change.  Please give it a whirl and let us know if you can now fully manage extension schema definitions through Graph Explorer.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Works like a charm, but I don't need the ownerid on DELETE for an InDevelopment schema.  You should also update the CREATE docs to include ownerid as an optional parameter.

Comment: Good to hear and thanks for confirming. Yes - DELETE doesn't have a payload, so naturally you don't need to specify it (duh on my part!).  Also, I spoke to the dev, and PATCH won't require it either, because owner is already set.  So the only one that requires it is POST.  We'll be making the updates to the docs shortly.